# MongoDB Atlas - Ruby connection not working inside Kubernetes

Tags: ruby, mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a Ruby script that connects to MongoDB Atlas for getting some data. It does work perfectly if I:

1. Run the script locally
2. Run the script locally with docker
3. Run the script in a separated AWS EC2 Instance
4. Run the script in docker inside a seperated AWS EC2 instance
5. Run the script inside local cluster with minikube.

However it doesn't work inside kubernetes, I am using EKS.

I have tried all items listed before and make sure the user exists on MongoDB Atlas.

This is pretty much the output that I receive:

```
User moon (mechanism: scram) is not authorized to access test (used mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1) (Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized)
```

I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding `&authSource=admin` to the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

What i have found:

- [Configure MongoDB Users](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/)
- Click Security > [Add new use](https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-atlas-cloud.html)

It looks like users permissions miss configuration:

As per documentation:
[Create a MongoDB User for Your Cluster](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/#create-a-mongodb-user-for-your-cluster).

> You must create a MongoDB user to access your deployment. For security purposes, Atlas requires clients to authenticate as MongoDB users to access clusters.
>
> MongoDB users are separate from Atlas users:
>
> MongoDB users can access databases hosted in Atlas.
>   Atlas users can log into Atlas but do not have access to MongoDB databases.

Hope this help.